Get error on accessing amazon extras installation on EC2 instance
Error on installing amazon-linux-extras on Amazon-linux 2 AMI

Command that i execute after connecting EC2 on terminal
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d.jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkind.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
get error here[error:],
[[errror:][(https://i.sstatic.net/FydyDiEV.png)]


error
230 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package epel-release-7-11.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Please provide the exact error message text instead of screenshots for better assistance.
